# Avoid nested try/except

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have the following code structure:

```
try:
    x = function_one(args)
    try:
        y = function_two(args)
        try:
            #
            # some code where I need x and y
            #
        except Exception as e::
            print("Problem with code above : ", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Problem with function_two : ", e)
    #
    # some code here
    #
except Exception as e:
        print("Problem with function_one : ", e)
```

It works but i was wondering if i can avoid this nested try/exception ?
For example if x is empty and can't be used after, would it be better to put the try / except inside function_one and find a solution to check if i can use x for the rest of the code, and if not, stop the code ?
I could do a `if x something` but it creates also nested part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your exception block is not doing something functional(proceeding with the rest of the code if it even has an error inside), you shouldn't use a nested try-catch block. Instead, you can write more exception blocks. For example,

```
try:
    x = function_one(args)
    
    y = function_two(args)
        
except Exceptionx as e:
        print("Problem with function_one : ", e)
except Exceptiony as e:
        print("Problem with function_two : ", e)
```

The *Exceptionx* and *Exceptiony* should be Exception class object and you should know that what kind of exception you would get. You can learn more examples at
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I think i'm going to do like this but adding a general except with a traceback as @Tomer Yogev said because i don't know which kind of exception it could create

Answer (score 2):

If you're only checking a certain block of code with a try\except, you can just wrap that block in the handler:

```
try:
    x = function_one(args)
except Exception as e:
        print("Problem with function_one : ", e)   
         
try:
    y = function_two(args)
except Exception as e:
   print("Problem with function_two : ", e)
   
try:
    #
    # some code where I need x and y
    #
except Exception as e::
    print("Problem with code above : ", e)
    
try:
    #
    # some code here
    #
except Exception as e::
    print("Problem with code above : ", e)
```

In general, only nest exception blocks if you plan to handle a more specific error in the inner block.

Comment: the problem with this one is that if i have an error in the first one i'll have at least one more in the third block i could avoid if i stopped after the first one

Answer (score 2):

If the reason for the different `except` blocks is to better understand where the error occurred, you can just wrap the whole block in a single `try-except` block and print the traceback:

```
import traceback

try:
    x = function_one(args)
    y = function_two(args)
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```